# Restoring from BackUp Exec to 2003 Recovery Storage Group

Tags: exchange-2003, backupexec

We seem to have some issue with recovering Exchange 2003 data via BackUp Exec 12.5 to Recovery Storage Group.

We have set-up a dial-tone Exchange database, and now trying to restore latest backup to new recovery group. Problem is, it seems as BackUp Exec recovers the data to the dial-tone database instead of Recovery Group.

There is no way to select destination in BackUp Exec, but I was sure Exchange alone knows where to restore data. I also double-checked the "this database can be overwritten by restore" check-boxes on dial-tone and recovery data-bases - it's unchecked on dial-tone, and checked on recovery, as instructed in every article.

Following this guide doesn't seem to help - it still restores to dial-tone:
http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH29719

P.S.: if this doesn't work, how safe is restoring the backup directly to dial-tone, and just using it as the production data-base from now on?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For for those wondering what a dial tone database is take a look at this article:[Recovering a Mailbox Database Using a Dial Tone Database in Exchange Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998947(EXCHG.65).aspx).  As far as your question goes the dialtone database will not have any of the server based rules that the user created, folder permissions, end encryption keys for OST files.  You can use the dial tone database as production but you will have to use exmerge to bring the old mail in.

See [Considerations and best practices when resetting an Exchange mailbox database](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=282496)